# UI processing causes audio glitches - should audio play on background thread?

Tags: ios, performance, uiview, core-audio

When you rotate the device, my app has quite a bit of logic to lay out the view differently for portrait/landscape - e.g. remove views, change frame sizes, redraw views, switch images etc.

Works flawlessly on new devices. On older devices if this is done while audio is playing it glitches considerably.

Is this most likely because the audio code is being blocked by the UI?  Should my audio play on a background thread?  The CPU even on an iPhone 4 is only about 20% during this transition so I don't it's a CPU issue.

I am using the loadPresetDemo example of [AUSampler](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2283/_index.html) to play audio and my thread looks like:

```
-(void)start
{
    playing = YES;

    if([NSThread isMainThread]) {
        NSThread *thread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(timerStart) object:nil];
        [thread start];
        return;
    }

    [[NSThread currentThread] setThreadPriority:1.0];
}


-(void)timerStart
{
    NSRunLoop *timerRunLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:intervalInMs/1000
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(beat)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
    [timerRunLoop run];
}


- (void)beat
{
    if(playing) {
        [audioPlayer beat];
        //UI thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [mView setBeat:audioPlayer.currentBeat];
        });
    }
}
```

AUSampler:

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import <AssertMacros.h>

// some MIDI constants:
enum {
    kMIDIMessage_NoteOn    = 0x9,
    kMIDIMessage_NoteOff   = 0x8,
};

#define kLowNote  48
#define kHighNote 72
#define kMidNote  60

// private class extension
@interface MainViewController ()
@property (readwrite) Float64   graphSampleRate;
@property (readwrite) AUGraph   processingGraph;
@property (readwrite) AudioUnit samplerUnit;
@property (readwrite) AudioUnit ioUnit;

- (OSStatus)    loadSynthFromPresetURL:(NSURL *) presetURL;
- (void)        registerForUIApplicationNotifications;
- (BOOL)        createAUGraph;
- (void)        configureAndStartAudioProcessingGraph: (AUGraph) graph;
- (void)        stopAudioProcessingGraph;
- (void)        restartAudioProcessingGraph;
@end

@implementation MainViewController

@synthesize graphSampleRate     = _graphSampleRate;
@synthesize currentPresetLabel  = _currentPresetLabel;
@synthesize presetOneButton     = _presetOneButton;
@synthesize presetTwoButton     = _presetTwoButton;
@synthesize lowNoteButton       = _lowNoteButton;
@synthesize midNoteButton       = _midNoteButton;
@synthesize highNoteButton      = _highNoteButton;
@synthesize samplerUnit         = _samplerUnit;
@synthesize ioUnit              = _ioUnit;
@synthesize processingGraph     = _processingGraph;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Audio setup


// Create an audio processing graph.
- (BOOL) createAUGraph {

    OSStatus result = noErr;
    AUNode samplerNode, ioNode;

    // Specify the common portion of an audio unit's identify, used for both audio units
    // in the graph.
    AudioComponentDescription cd = {};
    cd.componentManufacturer     = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
    cd.componentFlags            = 0;
    cd.componentFlagsMask        = 0;

    // Instantiate an audio processing graph
    result = NewAUGraph (&_processingGraph);
    NSCAssert (result == noErr, @"Unable to create an AUGraph object. Error code: %d '%.4s'", (int) result, (const char *)&result);

    //Specify the Sampler unit, to be used as the first node of the graph
    cd.componentType = kAudioUnitType_MusicDevice;
    cd.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_Sampler;

    // Add the Sampler unit node to the graph
    result = AUGraphAddNode (self.processingGraph, &cd, &samplerNode);
    NSCAssert (result == noErr, @"Unable to add the Sampler unit to the audio processing graph. Error code: %d '%.4s'", (int) result, (const char *)&result);

    // Specify the Output unit, to be used as the second and final node of the graph    
    cd.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
    cd.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;  

    // Add the Output unit node to the graph
    result = AUGraphAddNode (self.processingGraph, &cd, &ioNode);
    NSCAssert (result == noErr, @"Unable to add the Output unit to the audio processing graph. Error code: %d '%.4s'", (int) result, (const char *)&result);

    // Open the graph
    result = AUGraphOpen (self.processingGraph);
    NSCAssert (result == noErr, @"Unable to open the audio processing graph. Error code: %d '%.4s'", (int) result, (const char *)&result);

    // Connect the Sampler unit to the output unit
    result = AUGraphConnectNodeInput (self.processingGraph, samplerNode, 0, ioNode, 0);
    NSCAssert (result == noErr, @"Unable to interconnect the nodes in the audio processing graph. Error code: %d '%.4s'", (int) result, (const char *)&result);

    // Obtain a reference to the Sampler unit from its node
    result = AUGraphNodeInfo (self.processingGraph, samplerNode, 0, &_samplerUnit);
    NSCAssert (result == noErr, @"Unable to obtain a reference to the Sampler unit. Error code: %d '%.4s'", (int) result, (const char *)&result);

    // Obtain a reference to the I/O unit from its node
    result = AUGraphNodeInfo (self.processingGraph, ioNode, 0, &_ioUnit);
    NSCAssert (result == noErr, @"Unable to obtain a reference to the I/O unit. Error code: %d '%.4s'", (int) result, (const char *)&result);

    return YES;
}


// Starting with instantiated audio processing graph, configure its 
// audio units, initialize it, and start it.
- (void) configureAndStartAudioProcessingGraph: (AUGraph) graph {

    OSStatus result = noErr;
    UInt32 framesPerSlice = 0;
    UInt32 framesPerSlicePropertySize = sizeof (framesPerSlice);
    UInt32 sampleRatePropertySize = sizeof (self.graphSampleRate);

    result = AudioUnitInitialize (self.ioUnit);
    NSCAssert (result == noErr, @"Unable to initialize the I/O unit. Error code: %d '%.4s'", (int) result, (const char *)&result);

    // Set the I/O unit's output sample rate.
    result =    AudioUnitSetProperty (
                  self.ioUnit,
                  kAudioUnitProperty_SampleRate,
                  kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                  0,
                  &_graphSampleRate,
                  sampleRatePropertySize
                );

    NSAssert (result == noErr, @"AudioUnitSetProperty (set Sampler unit output stream sample rate). Error code: %d '%.4s'", (int) result, (const char *)&result);

    // Obtain the value of the maximum-frames-per-slice from the I/O unit.
    result =    AudioUnitGetProperty (
                    self.ioUnit,
                    kAudioUnitProperty_MaximumFramesPerSlice,
                    kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                    0,
                    &framesPerSlice,
                    &framesPerSlicePropertySize
                );

    NSCAssert (result == noErr, @"Unable to retrieve the maximum frames per slice property from the I/O unit. Error code: %d '%.4s'", (int) result, (const char *)&result);

    // Set the Sampler unit's output sample rate.
    result =    AudioUnitSetProperty (
                  self.samplerUnit,
                  kAudioUnitProperty_SampleRate,
                  kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                  0,
                  &_graphSampleRate,
                  sampleRatePropertySize
                );

    NSAssert (result == noErr, @"AudioUnitSetProperty (set Sampler unit output stream sample rate). Error code: %d '%.4s'", (int) result, (const char *)&result);

    // Set the Sampler unit's maximum frames-per-slice.
    result =    AudioUnitSetProperty (
                    self.samplerUnit,
                    kAudioUnitProperty_MaximumFramesPerSlice,
                    kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                    0,
                    &framesPerSlice,
                    framesPerSlicePropertySize
                );

    NSAssert( result == noErr, @"AudioUnitSetProperty (set Sampler unit maximum frames per slice). Error code: %d '%.4s'", (int) result, (const char *)&result);


    if (graph) {

        // Initialize the audio processing graph.
        result = AUGraphInitialize (graph);
        NSAssert (result == noErr, @"Unable to initialze AUGraph object. Error code: %d '%.4s'", (int) result, (const char *)&result);

        // Start the graph
        result = AUGraphStart (graph);
        NSAssert (result == noErr, @"Unable to start audio processing graph. Error code: %d '%.4s'", (int) result, (const char *)&result);

        // Print out the graph to the console
        CAShow (graph); 
    }
}


// Load the Trombone preset
- (IBAction)loadPresetOne:(id)sender {

    NSURL *presetURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Trombone" ofType:@"aupreset"]];
    if (presetURL) {
        NSLog(@"Attempting to load preset '%@'\n", [presetURL description]);
        self.currentPresetLabel.text = @"Trombone";
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"COULD NOT GET PRESET PATH!");
    }

    [self loadSynthFromPresetURL: presetURL];
}

// Load the Vibraphone preset
- (IBAction)loadPresetTwo:(id)sender {

    NSURL *presetURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Vibraphone" ofType:@"aupreset"]];
    if (presetURL) {
        NSLog(@"Attempting to load preset '%@'\n", [presetURL description]);
        self.currentPresetLabel.text = @"Vibraphone";   }
    else {
        NSLog(@"COULD NOT GET PRESET PATH!");
    }

    [self loadSynthFromPresetURL: presetURL];
}

// Load a synthesizer preset file and apply it to the Sampler unit
- (OSStatus) loadSynthFromPresetURL: (NSURL *) presetURL {

    CFDataRef propertyResourceData = 0;
    Boolean status;
    SInt32 errorCode = 0;
    OSStatus result = noErr;

    // Read from the URL and convert into a CFData chunk
    status = CFURLCreateDataAndPropertiesFromResource (
                kCFAllocatorDefault,
                (__bridge CFURLRef) presetURL,
                &propertyResourceData,
                NULL,
                NULL,
                &errorCode
             );

    NSAssert (status == YES && propertyResourceData != 0, @"Unable to create data and properties from a preset. Error code: %d '%.4s'", (int) errorCode, (const char *)&errorCode);

    // Convert the data object into a property list
    CFPropertyListRef presetPropertyList = 0;
    CFPropertyListFormat dataFormat = 0;
    CFErrorRef errorRef = 0;
    presetPropertyList = CFPropertyListCreateWithData (
                            kCFAllocatorDefault,
                            propertyResourceData,
                            kCFPropertyListImmutable,
                            &dataFormat,
                            &errorRef
                        );

    // Set the class info property for the Sampler unit using the property list as the value.
    if (presetPropertyList != 0) {

        result = AudioUnitSetProperty(
                    self.samplerUnit,
                    kAudioUnitProperty_ClassInfo,
                    kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                    0,
                    &presetPropertyList,
                    sizeof(CFPropertyListRef)
                );

        CFRelease(presetPropertyList);
    }

    if (errorRef) CFRelease(errorRef);
    CFRelease (propertyResourceData);

    return result;
}


// Set up the audio session for this app.
- (BOOL) setupAudioSession {

    AVAudioSession *mySession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

    // Specify that this object is the delegate of the audio session, so that
    //    this object's endInterruption method will be invoked when needed.
    [mySession setDelegate: self];

    // Assign the Playback category to the audio session. This category supports
    //    audio output with the Ring/Silent switch in the Silent position.
    NSError *audioSessionError = nil;
    [mySession setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &audioSessionError];
    if (audioSessionError != nil) {NSLog (@"Error setting audio session category."); return NO;}    

    // Request a desired hardware sample rate.
    self.graphSampleRate = 44100.0;    // Hertz

    [mySession setPreferredHardwareSampleRate: self.graphSampleRate error: &audioSessionError];
    if (audioSessionError != nil) {NSLog (@"Error setting preferred hardware sample rate."); return NO;}

    // Activate the audio session
    [mySession setActive: YES error: &audioSessionError];
    if (audioSessionError != nil) {NSLog (@"Error activating the audio session."); return NO;}

    // Obtain the actual hardware sample rate and store it for later use in the audio processing graph.
    self.graphSampleRate = [mySession currentHardwareSampleRate];

    return YES;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Audio control
// Play the low note
- (IBAction) startPlayLowNote:(id)sender {

    UInt32 noteNum = kLowNote;
    UInt32 onVelocity = 127;
    UInt32 noteCommand =    kMIDIMessage_NoteOn << 4 | 0;

    OSStatus result = noErr;
    require_noerr (result = MusicDeviceMIDIEvent (self.samplerUnit, noteCommand, noteNum, onVelocity, 0), logTheError);

logTheError:
    if (result != noErr) NSLog (@"Unable to start playing the low note. Error code: %d '%.4s'\n", (int) result, (const char *)&result);
}

// Stop the low note
- (IBAction) stopPlayLowNote:(id)sender {

    UInt32 noteNum = kLowNote;
    UInt32 noteCommand =    kMIDIMessage_NoteOff << 4 | 0;

    OSStatus result = noErr;
    require_noerr (result = MusicDeviceMIDIEvent (self.samplerUnit, noteCommand, noteNum, 0, 0), logTheError);

logTheError:
    if (result != noErr) NSLog (@"Unable to stop playing the low note. Error code: %d '%.4s'\n", (int) result, (const char *)&result);
}

// Play the mid note
- (IBAction) startPlayMidNote:(id)sender {

    UInt32 noteNum = kMidNote;
    UInt32 onVelocity = 127;
    UInt32 noteCommand =    kMIDIMessage_NoteOn << 4 | 0;

    OSStatus result = noErr;
    require_noerr (result = MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(self.samplerUnit, noteCommand, noteNum, onVelocity, 0), logTheError);

logTheError:
    if (result != noErr) NSLog (@"Unable to start playing the mid note. Error code: %d '%.4s'\n", (int) result, (const char *)&result);
}

// Stop the mid note
- (IBAction) stopPlayMidNote:(id)sender {

    UInt32 noteNum = kMidNote;
    UInt32 noteCommand =    kMIDIMessage_NoteOff << 4 | 0;

    OSStatus result = noErr;
    require_noerr (result = MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(self.samplerUnit, noteCommand, noteNum, 0, 0), logTheError);

logTheError:
    if (result != noErr) NSLog (@"Unable to stop playing the mid note. Error code: %d '%.4s'\n", (int) result, (const char *)&result);
}

// Play the high note
- (IBAction) startPlayHighNote:(id)sender {

    UInt32 noteNum = kHighNote;
    UInt32 onVelocity = 127;
    UInt32 noteCommand =    kMIDIMessage_NoteOn << 4 | 0;

    OSStatus result = noErr;
    require_noerr (result = MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(self.samplerUnit, noteCommand, noteNum, onVelocity, 0), logTheError);

logTheError:
    if (result != noErr) NSLog (@"Unable to start playing the high note. Error code: %d '%.4s'\n", (int) result, (const char *)&result);
}

// Stop the high note
- (IBAction)stopPlayHighNote:(id)sender {

    UInt32 noteNum = kHighNote;
    UInt32 noteCommand =    kMIDIMessage_NoteOff << 4 | 0;

    OSStatus result = noErr;
    require_noerr (result = MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(self.samplerUnit, noteCommand, noteNum, 0, 0), logTheError);

logTheError:
    if (result != noErr) NSLog (@"Unable to stop playing the high note. Error code: %d '%.4s'", (int) result, (const char *)&result);
}

// Stop the audio processing graph
- (void) stopAudioProcessingGraph {

    OSStatus result = noErr;
    if (self.processingGraph) result = AUGraphStop(self.processingGraph);
    NSAssert (result == noErr, @"Unable to stop the audio processing graph. Error code: %d '%.4s'", (int) result, (const char *)&result);
}

// Restart the audio processing graph
- (void) restartAudioProcessingGraph {

    OSStatus result = noErr;
    if (self.processingGraph) result = AUGraphStart (self.processingGraph);
    NSAssert (result == noErr, @"Unable to restart the audio processing graph. Error code: %d '%.4s'", (int) result, (const char *)&result);
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Audio session delegate methods

// Respond to an audio interruption, such as a phone call or a Clock alarm.
- (void) beginInterruption {

    // Stop any notes that are currently playing.
    [self stopPlayLowNote: self];
    [self stopPlayMidNote: self];
    [self stopPlayHighNote: self];

    // Interruptions do not put an AUGraph object into a "stopped" state, so
    //    do that here.
    [self stopAudioProcessingGraph];
}


// Respond to the ending of an audio interruption.
- (void) endInterruptionWithFlags: (NSUInteger) flags {

    NSError *endInterruptionError = nil;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES
                                         error: &endInterruptionError];
    if (endInterruptionError != nil) {

        NSLog (@"Unable to reactivate the audio session.");
        return;
    }

    if (flags & AVAudioSessionInterruptionFlags_ShouldResume) {

        /*
         In a shipping application, check here to see if the hardware sample rate changed from 
         its previous value by comparing it to graphSampleRate. If it did change, reconfigure 
         the ioInputStreamFormat struct to use the new sample rate, and set the new stream 
         format on the two audio units. (On the mixer, you just need to change the sample rate).

         Then call AUGraphUpdate on the graph before starting it.
         */

        [self restartAudioProcessingGraph];
    }
}


#pragma mark - Application state management

// The audio processing graph should not run when the screen is locked or when the app has 
//  transitioned to the background, because there can be no user interaction in those states.
//  (Leaving the graph running with the screen locked wastes a significant amount of energy.)
//
// Responding to these UIApplication notifications allows this class to stop and restart the 
//    graph as appropriate.
- (void) registerForUIApplicationNotifications {

    NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

    [notificationCenter addObserver: self
                           selector: @selector (handleResigningActive:)
                               name: UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
                             object: [UIApplication sharedApplication]];

    [notificationCenter addObserver: self
                           selector: @selector (handleBecomingActive:)
                               name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                             object: [UIApplication sharedApplication]];
}


- (void) handleResigningActive: (id) notification {

    [self stopPlayLowNote: self];
    [self stopPlayMidNote: self];
    [self stopPlayHighNote: self];
    [self stopAudioProcessingGraph];
}


- (void) handleBecomingActive: (id) notification {

    [self restartAudioProcessingGraph];
}

- (id) initWithNibName: (NSString *) nibNameOrNil bundle: (NSBundle *) nibBundleOrNil {

    self = [super initWithNibName: nibNameOrNil bundle: nibBundleOrNil];

    // If object initialization fails, return immediately.
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Set up the audio session for this app, in the process obtaining the 
    // hardware sample rate for use in the audio processing graph.
    BOOL audioSessionActivated = [self setupAudioSession];
    NSAssert (audioSessionActivated == YES, @"Unable to set up audio session.");

    // Create the audio processing graph; place references to the graph and to the Sampler unit
    // into the processingGraph and samplerUnit instance variables.
    [self createAUGraph];
    [self configureAndStartAudioProcessingGraph: self.processingGraph];

    return self;
}


- (void) viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Load the Trombone preset so the app is ready to play upon launch.
    [self loadPresetOne: self];
    [self registerForUIApplicationNotifications];
}

- (void) viewDidUnload {

    self.currentPresetLabel = nil;
    self.presetOneButton    = nil;
    self.presetTwoButton    = nil;
    self.lowNoteButton      = nil;
    self.midNoteButton      = nil;
    self.highNoteButton     = nil;

    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (void) didReceiveMemoryWarning {

    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}


@end
```

Answer (score 2):

An NSTimer, in any thread, is unsuitable for precise musical timing, or anything where the app needs a timing accuracy better than within 50 milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks, yes I know that but it works fine for what I need it to do.  The issue occurs when the device is rotated and the UI is laid out again. Surely a more accurate timer will still suffer the same.

Comment: The audio sample clock suffices.  Properly written Audio Unit callbacks (short, with no memory management or other unbounded latency code) do not appear to be blocked by any UI activity.  NSTimers can be blocked, and thus are not suitable.

Comment: Yes you are right. It's the timer that's being blocked - it's delays firing the method when the device is rotated. However I replaced it with TPPreciseTimer as suggested by Adam and the same thing occurs

Comment: No OS timer will be as accurate for audio as the Audio Unit sample clock (or time), which may far nearer to what is required for a professional quality percussion track or metronome.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that your high priority timer thread is interfering with the core audio thread on these older devices. Try moving to a lower priority and reducing the time interval of your timer to test this theory. This would be a bug in Apple's code – the audio thread is the highest priority thread on iOS, and the os is supposed to insure that no user code interrupts it long enough to cause stutters, but it does happen. That said, you probably shouldn't be using a timer like this to trigger audio for most kinds of musical applications, but should rather use the timestamps core audio provides in the render callback (see RemoteIO) to handle timing. Here's a pretty good discussion:

http://atastypixel.com/blog/experiments-with-precise-timing-in-ios/

> > "Also note that there are often ways to eliminate the need for precise timing of this nature, by architecting code appropriately — when it comes to audio, for example, CoreAudio provides a very accurate time base in render callbacks. For things like metronomes or audio synthesizers, it’s always better to establish a starting time, and use the difference between the current time and the starting time in order to determine state, rather than using a timer to advance the state."

Comment: Thanks Adam. I implemented TPPreciseTimer which works great. Having run some tests logging the output it appears that it's my `beat` method is delayed when the device is rotated so it doesn't fire the play/stop methods correctly and glitches.  This should be on a separate thread so unsure why this is happening